# Typescript - type of output to depend on type of input

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function that checks validity of input fields.

```
export const getInputValidity = (inputData:DeepReadonly<InputData> , val:string) => {
    const {length} = val
    if (inputData.type==="select"){
        return val.length<5
    } 
    if (inputData.type==="email"){
        return {
            validEdit: !length || isExp(val, /^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~."(),:;<>@[\]]+$/), 
            validFinal: length && isExp(val, COMMON_REGEX.email)
        } 
    }
}
```

I want the output to depend on the input

```
const validity = getInputValidity(EMAIL_INPUT_DATA, emailVal )
```

So if `EMAIL_INPUT_DATA.type==="email"` I'd like the type of validity will be

```
{
   validEdit: boolean
   validFinal: boolean
}
```

Is it possible? Currently validity is typed as

```
const validity: true | {
    readonly validEdit: boolean;
    readonly validFinal: boolean | 0;
    readonly validLength?: undefined;
    readonly validChars?: undefined;
} | {
    readonly validLength: boolean;
    readonly validChars: boolean;
    readonly validEdit?: undefined;
    readonly validFinal?: undefined;
}
```

I understand that this could be done by typing getInputValidity as a function, but could it be inferred from implementation?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that you'd like to return a different type of object when the function is called with different arguments?

Comment: @OliverRadini, the "type" field might be confusing here, but I'm not looking to change the functionality of the function, but just the typing. When we pass inputData with "select" as the type field we humans know that the return type would be of type boolean, and when we pass "email" as type field we humans know that the return type would be {validEdit:boolean, validFinal:boolean} however the compiler doesn't recognize that.

Comment: ah ok, I think that makes sense then - you're trying to return `{ validEdit: boolean; validFinal: boolean; ` when the input type is `"email"`, and `boolean` if it is `"select"`?

Comment: @OliverRadini, correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to do this:

```js
const isExp = (s: String, r: RegExp) => true;

interface IValidityReturn {
  validEdit: boolean;
  validFinal: boolean;
}

function getInputValidity(inputData: { type: 'select' }, val: string): boolean;
function getInputValidity(inputData: { type: 'select' }, val: string): boolean;
function getInputValidity(inputData: { type: 'select' | 'email' }, val: string): boolean | IValidityReturn {
    const { length } = val
    
    if (inputData.type==="select"){
        return val.length<5
    }

    if (inputData.type==="email"){
        return {
            validEdit: !length || isExp(val, /^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~."(),:;<>@[\]]+$/), 
            validFinal: !!length && isExp(val, /a/g),
        } 
    }

    // only to make example work:
    return {
      validEdit: false,
      validFinal: false,
    }
}
```

Some of these parts are pieced together for the purpose of the example, but it seems as though this should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! However, as I mentioned "I understand that this could be done by typing getInputValidity as a function, but could it be inferred from implementation?" I'm aware that it could be solved in such a way. I am not sure why Typescript can't recongnize the return type from implementation,and if it is possible. There are additional types (besides "select" and "email") and if I need to prepare a overload for each case, I rather go in a different direction.

Comment: @bencarp typescript is able to infer some, but not all details from implementation, but these are mostly centered around type guards. Your code makes this sort of type inference look relatively straight forward, but in reality it'd be remarkably complicated. You're asking typescript to be able to essentially run the code, and use that to make assumptions about the type which comes out, which quickly becomes very difficult